# Is there a possibility to write information into IOS keychain pragmatically...?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am generating a random strong password for every user and want the user to use the same password for accessing the application, since the password is going to be hard to remember I wish to store the same in the keychain so it is easy to access.

Comment: Have you considered instead using the Apple API to generate and store passwords in the keychain? For example "[Adding a Password to the Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/adding_a_password_to_the_keychain)", or "[About the Password AutoFill Workflow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow)". There are also tutorials available if you search the internet using the words "swift 5 keychain password".

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, you must be looking for [nativescript-secure-storage](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-secure-storage) plugin.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-secure-storage
```